# How to show more than 10 Accounts on Parity's UI?

Tags: parity, parity-wallet

Parity only shows 10 accounts by default. I have 50 different Ethereum accounts that I'd like to see all within the Parity Account tab. How can that be done?

Comment: Are you talking about the signer which let's you only chose 10 accounts to select from?